# What embedded Language is this?

Tags: xml

I have a file that I'm trying to figure out. It is being run by an embedded system running Windows Embedded CE. Obviously it's an XML file, but all of the statements within the tags really have me scratching my head. I've never seen anything like it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MAIN>
  <INIT>
    <NAME>Init</NAME>
    <STATEMENT>SET_ANOUT: anFlowSpeed 1 100;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: sftNoProductIn = TRUE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>FORMAT: %gi.TinyStatus = 0;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>IF: inPressFixtureDown = FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>GOTO: Init1;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ELSE:;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>IF: inSideAdjustWork = FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>GOTO: Init2;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ELSE:;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>GOTO: Init3;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ENDIF:;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ENDIF:;</STATEMENT>
    <COMMENT />
    <COMMENT>//INIT 1, FIXTURE WAS NOT DOWN</COMMENT>
    <STATEMENT>LABEL: Init1;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SUB: FIXTUREDOWN;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: ProductHolder WORK_24;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>DELAY: T#2s;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ROBOT: ConvUp POWER_ON;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ROBOT: ConvUp CALIB_NOWAIT;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ROBOT: ConvUp WAIT_CALIB DUMMY TO:T#12s;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: ProductSideAdjust WORK_20;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ROBOT: ConvUp MOVE Loc_UpConvProduct TO:T#12s;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: ProductHolder HOME_14;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>GOTO: InitCheckDownConv;</STATEMENT>
    <COMMENT></COMMENT>
    <COMMENT>//INIT2, FIXTURE WAS DOWN, SIDE ADJUST IN HOME</COMMENT>
    <STATEMENT>LABEL: Init2;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ROBOT: ConvUp POWER_ON;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ROBOT: ConvUp CALIB_NOWAIT;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ROBOT: ConvUp WAIT_CALIB DUMMY TO:T#12s;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: ProductHolder WORK_24;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>DELAY: T#2s;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: ProductSideAdjust WORK_20;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ROBOT: ConvUp MOVE Loc_UpConvProduct TO:T#12s;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: ProductHolder HOME_14;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>GOTO: InitCheckDownConv;</STATEMENT>
    <COMMENT></COMMENT>
    <COMMENT>//INIT3, FIXTURE WAS DOWN, SIDE ADJUST WORK</COMMENT>
    <STATEMENT>LABEL: Init3;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ROBOT: ConvUp POWER_ON;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ROBOT: ConvUp CALIB_NOWAIT;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ROBOT: ConvUp WAIT_CALIB DUMMY TO:T#12s;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ROBOT: ConvUp MOVE Loc_UpConvProduct TO:T#12s;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>GOTO: InitCheckDownConv;</STATEMENT>
    <COMMENT></COMMENT>
    <COMMENT>// INIT CHECK DOWN CONVEYOR, REMOVE POSSIBLE PRODUCT, CHECK CONNECTION TO UP/DOWN FIXTURE</COMMENT>
    <STATEMENT>LABEL: InitCheckDownConv;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SUB: DETECT_DOWN_FIXTURE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SUB: DETECT_UP_FIXTURE;</STATEMENT>
    <COMMENT></COMMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ROBOT: ConvUp WAIT_CALIB DUMMY TO:T#12s;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ROBOT: ConvDown POWER_ON;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ROBOT: ConvDown CALIB_NOWAIT;</STATEMENT>
    <COMMENT>JOTAPI: JOTAPI INITIALIZATE 1;</COMMENT>
    <COMMENT>JOTAPI: LMSJOTAPI INITIALIZATE 2;</COMMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ROBOT: ConvDown WAIT_CALIB DUMMY TO:T#12s;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ROBOT: ConvDown MOVE Loc_DownConvProduct TO:T#12s;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>EXECUTE: TEST;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>FORMAT: %gi.TinyStatus = 1;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>END:;</STATEMENT>
  </INIT>
  <EXECUTION>
    <NAME>TEST</NAME>
    <STATEMENT>LABEL: Start;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>IF: inPressFixtureDown = TRUE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtTopConnector HOME_10;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtDownConnector HOME_10;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtureTopLock HOME_10;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtureDownLock HOME_10;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>DELAY: T#1s;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtureDownLock WORK_20;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtureTopLock WORK_20;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtDownConnector WORK_20;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtTopConnector WORK_20;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>DELAY: T#1s;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtDownChange WORK_20;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>DELAY: T#1s;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtDownChange HOME_10;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ROBOT: ConvUp MOVE Loc_UpConvProduct AX:1 WD:999;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: ProductSideAdjust WORK_24;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ROBOT: ConvUp WAIT_INPOS DUMMY TO:T#12s;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ROBOT: ConvDown MOVE Loc_DownConvProduct TO:T#12s;;</STATEMENT>
    <COMMENT>// CONVEYORS RUN</COMMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_ANOUT: anSpeedConvUp 1 100;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_ANOUT: anSpeedConvDown 1 100;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: outConvUpDir=TRUE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: outConvDownDir=TRUE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: outConvUpRun=TRUE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: outConvDownRun=TRUE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>DELAY: T#1500ms;</STATEMENT>
    <COMMENT>// CHANGE CONVEYOR DIRECTION</COMMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: outConvUpDir=FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: outConvDownDir=FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>DELAY: T#1500ms;</STATEMENT>
    <COMMENT>// HALT CONVEYORS</COMMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: outConvUpRun=FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: outConvUpDir=FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: outConvDownRun=FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: outConvDownDir=FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ROBOT: ConvUp MOVE Loc_UpConvSafe AX:1 WD:999;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: ProductSideAdjust HOME_14;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ROBOT: ConvUp WAIT_INPOS DUMMY TO:T#12s;;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ROBOT: ConvDown MOVE Loc_DownConvSafe AX:1 WD:999;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: ProductSideAdjust HOME_14;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>IF: sftNoFixtureIn = FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: ProductStopper WORK_20;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: ProductHolder WORK_20;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ENDIF:;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ROBOT: ConvDown WAIT_INPOS DUMMY TO:T#12s;;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>IF: sftNoFixtureIn = FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: ProductStopper HOME_10;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: ProductHolder HOME_10;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ENDIF:;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SUB: FIXTUREUP TRUE;</STATEMENT>
    <COMMENT>// ADD POSSIBLE CONVEYOR OPERATION HERE</COMMENT>
    <STATEMENT>DELAY: T#2000ms;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SUB: FIXTUREDOWN;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>GOTO: Start;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ENDIF:;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>END:;</STATEMENT>
  </EXECUTION>
  <SUB>
    <NAME>DETECT_UP_FIXTURE</NAME>
    <COMMENT>// IF TESTING ENSURE THAT TOP FIXTURE IS IN PLACE</COMMENT>
    <STATEMENT>LABEL: TryAgainUp;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>IF: inFixTopConnConnected = FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtTopConnector HOME_14;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ENDIF:;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>IF: inFixtureTopLock = FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtureTopLock HOME_14;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>DELAY: T#1s;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtureTopLock WORK_24;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ENDIF:;</STATEMENT>
    <COMMENT></COMMENT>
    <STATEMENT>DELAY: T#1s;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>IF: inFixtureTopLock = TRUE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtTopConnector WORK_24;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ELSE:;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtureTopLock HOME_14;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ERROR: CONNECT_FIXTURE NoFixture 10011 1 1;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>GOTO: TryAgainUp;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ENDIF:;</STATEMENT>
    <COMMENT></COMMENT>
    <STATEMENT>DELAY: T#1s;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>IF: inUpperFixtureIn = FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtTopConnector HOME_14;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>DELAY: T#500ms;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: sftNoFixtureIn = TRUE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtureTopLock HOME_14;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: sftNoFixtureIn = TRUE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>FORMAT: %gs.ErrWarDes = NOUPPERFIXTURE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ERROR: WARNING NOFIXTURE 0 2 2 ErrWarDes;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ENDIF:;</STATEMENT>
    <COMMENT></COMMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtureTopLock WORK_20;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtTopConnector WORK_20;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>END:;</STATEMENT>
  </SUB>
  <SUB>
    <NAME>DETECT_DOWN_FIXTURE</NAME>
    <COMMENT />
    <COMMENT>// IF TESTING ENSURE THAT LOWER FIXTURE IS IN PLACE</COMMENT>
    <COMMENT></COMMENT>
    <STATEMENT>LABEL: TryAgainDown;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>IF: inFixDownConnConnected = FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtDownConnector HOME_14;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ENDIF:;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>IF: inFixtureDownLock = FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtureDownLock HOME_14;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>DELAY: T#1s;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtureDownLock WORK_24;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ENDIF:;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtDownChange HOME_10;</STATEMENT>
    <COMMENT></COMMENT>
    <STATEMENT>DELAY: T#1s;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>IF: inFixtureDownLock = TRUE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtDownConnector WORK_24;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ELSE:;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtDownConnector HOME_14;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>DELAY: T#500ms;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtureDownLock HOME_14;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtDownChange WORK_20;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ERROR: CONNECT_FIXTURE NoFixture 10021 1 1;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>GOTO: TryAgainDown;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ENDIF:;</STATEMENT>
    <COMMENT></COMMENT>
    <STATEMENT>DELAY: T#1s;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>IF: inLowerFixtureIn = FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtDownConnector HOME_14;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>DELAY: T#500ms;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtureDownLock HOME_14;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtDownChange WORK_20;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: sftNoFixtureIn = TRUE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>FORMAT: %gs.ErrWarDes = NOLOWERFIXTURE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ERROR: WARNING NOFIXTURE 0 2 2 ErrWarDes;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ENDIF:;</STATEMENT>
    <COMMENT />
    <STATEMENT>IF: sftNoFixtureIn = FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>IF: inFixtureDownLock = FALSE OR inFixDownConnConnected = FALSE OR inProdHolderHome = FALSE AND inProdHolderWork = FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtDownConnector HOME_14;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>DELAY: T#500ms;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtureDownLock HOME_14;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtDownChange WORK_20;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ERROR: CONNECT_FIXTURE NoFixture 10023 1 1;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>GOTO: TryAgainDown;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ENDIF:;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ENDIF:;</STATEMENT>
    <COMMENT></COMMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtureDownLock WORK_20;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtDownConnector WORK_20;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: FixtDownChange HOME_10;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>END:;</STATEMENT>
  </SUB>
  <SUB>
    <NAME>FIXTUREUP</NAME>
    <PARAMETERS>bWaitSensor</PARAMETERS>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: outFlowControlEN = TRUE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_ANOUT: anFlowSpeed 1 100;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: outPressFixtManualUp = FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: outPressFixtManualDown = FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>IF: bWaitSensor = TRUE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: PressFixtureAuto WORK_24;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>WAIT_IN: inPressFixtureMid = TRUE T#4s;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_ANOUT: anFlowSpeed 1 %gi.ClosingSpeed;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>WAIT_IN: inPressFixtureUp = TRUE T#10s;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_ANOUT: anFlowSpeed 1 100;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: outPressFixtManualUp = TRUE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: PressFixtureAuto WORK_20;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ELSE:;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: PressFixtureManual WORK_20;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ENDIF:;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: outFlowControlEN = FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>END:;</STATEMENT>
  </SUB>
  <SUB>
    <NAME>FIXTUREDOWN</NAME>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: outFlowControlEN = TRUE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_ANOUT: anFlowSpeed 1 100;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: outPressFixtAutoUp = FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: outPressFixtAutoDown = FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <COMMENT>(*SET_OUT: outPressFixtManualDown = TRUE;*)</COMMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: PressFixtureManual HOME_10;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: outPressFixtManualUp = FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ACTUATOR: PressFixtureAuto HOME_10;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: outPressFixtManualDown = FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: outPressFixtManualUp = FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: outFlowControlEN = FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>END:;</STATEMENT>
  </SUB>
  <STOP>
    <NAME>STOP</NAME>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: sftStopFlag = TRUE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>END:;</STATEMENT>
  </STOP>
  <START>
    <NAME>START</NAME>
    <STATEMENT>IF: sftStopFlag = TRUE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>SET_OUT: sftStopFlag = FALSE;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>ENDIF:;</STATEMENT>
    <STATEMENT>END:;</STATEMENT>
  </START>
</MAIN>
```

I am not sure if the XML tags are actually part of the language or if the real code is simply piggybacking within XML tags for interpretation by the system. Does anyone have any idea as to what this could be?

Comment: delete it. its junk. check out : http://www.theoldrobots.com/book45/ACL28-Ctrl-B.pdf

Comment: This looks like an xml file that is used as input to a manufacture machine.  The machine has a convey belt.  It could be a machine that is used to mold a plastic objects, but I'm only guessing.

Comment: @THEAMAZING It does look pretty similar to ALC. Are you saying it's likely a corrupted/broken ALC program? It does run but always gets hung up at some point, although I haven't yet been able to determine if it's a software or hardware issue.